# Secure access to an ASMX Service from a Cordova (PhoneGap) Application

Tags: vb.net, cordova, security, asmx

I have built my app using `PhoneGap` and everything is working fine. My question is regarding security of this access.

In this app, the user needs to login providing username and password (which I keep in `localStorage`). After logged in, the app calls a lot of WebService methods and there is no security (I can get data even from URL in the browser passing the correct params).

The existing security (almost none) is good enough to regular users, but it is not difficult to verify HTML and discover what are the params of WebService and get the data.

A way I thought is always pass `username` and `password` to server as method params to check if that user is able to get that data.

**What is the best approach?**

---

I can call the WebService from URL like:

http://benfaniz.com.br/WebService.asmx/AAA_Buscar_Nome_Condominio

With Javascript I use:

```
var theUrl = "https://benfaniz.com.br/webservice.asmx/AAA_Buscar_Nome_Condominio";
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      //the code after getting data
   };
xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Since, the data is in XML format, I also use the following script to convert data to JSON (I don't think it is relevant for the question but it could help someone)

```
<script src="https://jquery-xml2json-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.xml2json.js"></script>
```

The WebService method is defined like:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)> _
Function AAA_Buscar_Nome_Condominio() As String
    Dim _Condominio As ClCondominio = ClCondominio.Retorna_Condominio(1)
    Return _Condominio.Nome
End Function
```

Comment: What language and platform is your service written in? For instance, is in RPG for the AS400?

Comment: Sorry, this is very relevant. I wrote it in VB.NET

Comment: BTW, the word you need to search for is "authentication"

Comment: I'm agreeing with you. I believe the language of the Webservice is very relevant for a possible solution the users would suggest. I am using VS2013.

Comment: Also, are you using WCF to write the services?

Comment: No. They are in my WebSite project. Is there a way to allow calls only from specific domain, for example?

Comment: Another useful piece of information you didn't include: are you using a web site "project" (File->New Web Site), or a Web Application Project (File->New Project)? Maybe you should even show a little code???

Comment: I am using Website project. I will improve my question adding code with a live example of the way I access the WebService

Comment: You seem to be using "Page Methods" with a Web Site "project". That's a lot like the blind leading the blind. Web site "projects" are not projects, and should not be used for anything serious. "Page Methods" are  a subset of the legacy ASMX technology, which should not be used for new development. Among other things, they have no security at all! The best you can do is to pass a username/password or something like that on every call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80005/discussion-between-nizam-and-john-saunders).

Comment: Ok @John, I got your suggestion. I have read it here (https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/). Thanks!!!!

Comment: Ok, for the record, these are not page methods, just good old-fashioned (legacy) ASMX web services. You _can_ do some simple authentication with these. For instance, you could add a "Login" operation which accepted username and password, and returned some unique value (a token) if login is successful. Subsequent calls would require that this token be passed. You could do this using SOAP Headers. This assumes that your Cordova application is able to use the features of SOAP.

Comment: Great!!! Something like I was intending, but even better. I will to rewrite the code using WCF. While I am not able to do it, I will follow the token suggestion. Would you please formulate an answer with your suggestion (including the one to not use the legacy ASMX)? I would be glad to accept it.