# Controlling access to asmx using tokens

Tags: asp.net, web-services, token, asmx, basic-authentication

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721382/secure-access-to-an-asmx-service-from-a-cordova-phonegap-application), it was suggested to use `token`, given by server after user authentication, to control the access to webservice methods.

The idea is quite simple. After login, the server passes to client a token that is used to call methods.

My question is:

**How would server know that token is valid? A table with tokens and expiration date is a good approach?**

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I see, but even this way I would have to use tokens to control access, right?

Comment: You mean even with WCF? No. WCF supports several industry-standard security mechanisms. ASMX supports ***no*** industry-standard security mechanisms.

Comment: It's always a bad idea to create your own security mechanisms. There are people who do that for a living - you should take advantage of their hard work. There are also people who break into systems for a living. You should let them fight the people who write security systems for a living - don't have them fight you (and win).

Comment: Even for an access from a plain HTML? The examples I am finding is accessing services without worrying about security (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2008/02/18/how-to-consume-wcf-using-ajax-without-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: ASMX services _have_ no security. That link is for WCF.

Comment: Suppose I convert my webservice for WCF, how would I access it, from plain HTML, with security? I would have a username and password of client, but how would I use this info to call a WCF service? The examples I saw are passing username and password in header, but I also can do this with ASMX services. Is there another way?

Comment: There are a lot of different ways. The thing with using WCF is that you can take advantage of industry-standard security. ASMX was created in the days of .NET 1.0 - before there _were_ any industry standards. Think about it - there was no **AJAX**!